# M2.2.2 Remove default schema.org rich snippets

Tags: magento2, rich-snippets, structured-data

[image]

I have installed an extension which puts Rich Cards on my product pages, however the default Magento structured data code for rich snippets is still present. How can I remove this from product pages?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This helps me to remove Magento default product schema by following steps. 
**1. Remove product schema from body. Add this to catalog_product_view.xml under your theme.**

```
<body>
    <attribute name="itemtype" remove="true"/>
    <attribute name="itemscope" remove="true"/>
</body>
```

**2. Remove aggregateRating**

Copy this to your theme

```
vendor/magento/module-review/view/frontend/templates/helper/summary.phtml
```

remove

```
itemprop="aggregateRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating"
```

**3. Remove Review**

Copy this to your theme

```
vendor/magento/module-review/view/frontend/templates/product/view/list.phtml
```

Remove

```
itemscope itemprop="review" itemtype="http://schema.org/Review"
```

**Note:** missing #2 and #3 will receive an error similar to below in validation due to action #1

```
“The review has no reviewed item specified.”
```

Comment: Whether it will remove the entire default schema.org? Or only remove review  and aggregateRating

Answer (score 8):

When I added `remove='true'` to these attributes -  I got the following error:

`Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'attribute', attribute 'remove': The attribute 'remove' is not allowed.`

To get these properties to disappear, I changed them to this instead:

```
<attribute name="itemtype" value="" />
<attribute name="itemscope" value="" />
```

Reference for the Solution:

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/10889

Answer (score 4):

You can remove the default schema.org from catalog_product_view.xml file. Add below the line of code:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>            
    <attribute name="itemtype" value=""/>
    <attribute name="itemscope" value=""/>
</body>
</page>
```