# Magento 2.3.1 how to disable default rich snippets

Tags: magento2, rich-snippets

i install a 3rd party rich snippets on my site that comes with porto theme i have done a structured data test today and it,s shows 2 sets of product now google always picking the default one.
can some one help me to remove magento default rich snippets so i can use the 3rd party rich snippets

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/208802/m2-2-2-remove-default-schema-org-rich-snippets?rq=1

Comment: if i do that i got error message on frontend removing attribute not allowed

Answer (score 0):

**Using This Module You Can Remove Default Rich Snippets :-**

[magento-2-remove-default-rich-snippets](https://www.magmodules.eu/blog/magento-2-remove-default-rich-snippets/)

[remove-default-magento-snippets](https://www.magmodules.eu/help/magento-2-rich-snippets-suite/remove-default-magento-snippets)

Comment: already tried this didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Follow below instruction.

in etc/di.xml add below code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
  <preference for="Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render\Amount" type="YourPackage\Yourmodule\Model\Pricing\Render\Amount" />    
</config>
```

Create Amount.php under app\code\YourPackage\Yourmodule\Model\Pricing\Render add below code

```
<?php

namespace YourPackage\Yourmodule\Model\Pricing\Render;


class Amount extends \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render\Amount
{
    public function getSchema()
    {
         return false;

    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry that didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Did anyone solve this issue in the end? I too have porto and a third party rich snippet module, resulting in the same issue.